# How is this integral calculated?

Tags: calculus, analysis

[image: Integral of function sequence]

How is this integral calculated? I can't seem to understand how they get $4/j²$.

Comment: This is actually wrong. The integral is just $2/j$, since $f_j^2=1$ on an interval of length $2/j$. It converges to zero nonetheless.

Comment: okay but $\displaystyle \int f(x)^2\,dx \neq \left(\int f(x)\,dx \right)^2$ in general

Answer (score 1):

Well, we know that $\displaystyle |f_j-0|^2$ is $1$ if $\displaystyle x \in \left[-\frac{1}{j}, \frac{1}{j}\right]$ and $0$ otherwise.

Then, the integral is equal to $\displaystyle \frac{2}{j}$.

Perhaps they were referring to $\displaystyle \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left|f_j-0 \right|\,dx\right)^2$, otherwise it is a clear blunder.